# problems to transmit beacon from android device

Tags: android

Has anybody used Samsung's Bluetooth LE APIs to make a Samsung Android device advertise as an iBeacon? i am using samsung galaxy s4 ( GT- i9500)device for transmitting advertisement using altbeacon library . but my code not working is there any problems please check.

```
    Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6") // UUID for beacon
            .setId2("1") // Major for beacon
            .setId3("5") // Minor for beacon
            .setManufacturer(0x004C) // Radius Networks.0x0118  Change this for other beacon layouts//0x004C for iPhone
            .setTxPower(-56) // Power in dB
            .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l})) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
            .build();

    BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");

    BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Advertisement start failed with code: " + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Advertisement start succeeded.");
        }
    });
```

Comment: try keeping the beacon as far away as possible from your workdesk

Comment: iam not understanding that what is the use of .setManufacturer(0x004C)...is there any need to change ..that

Comment: and please also tell me about setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");..actually i installed Locate App from play store and set id 1 and id2 and id 3  but it crashed....i am not getting reason why app crashed..